# Amazon SQL job interview question: customers who made 2+ purchases

Tags: sql

You have a simple table that has only two fields: CustomerID, DateOfPurchase. List all customers that made at least 2 purchases in any period of six months. You may assume the table has the data for the last 10 years. Also, there is no PK or unique value.

My friend already got the job, despite the fact that he couldn't answer this question. I was curious how this kind of question can be solved.

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on the particular database being used here.  You should immediately have fired back this question to your interviewer.

Comment: This was actually my friend's job interview. But let's assume MS SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

- From an abstract view this problem is about efficiently self joining a table with no PK or unique identifier.
- This is very tricky as you see there can be scenarios like

  - a customer making **exactly 2 purchase in 6 month** that too on same date (which can look like duplicate record)
  - a customer making >=2 purchase in 6 month on different date(the usual case).
- One of the thing that needs to be done here is *generate a column that can **act**
  like a unique identifier* which can be achieved here using `row_number`
- After having a unique identifier it is easy to join on your required conditions **and unique identifier from 1st alias != unique identifier from 2nd alias** (meaning joining all rows from both alias **except with same row**, **same row !=  different row with same data** as in 1st scenario)
- Putting it all together, it can achieved using

  - [common table expressions](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/using-common-table-expressions/) to start with a single source of data that **includes a manually added unique identifier** and then doing the required business
  - [row_number](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) which helps us assign that unique identifier to our single source of data generated in a common table expression.
- refer the below query for technical details.

```
with tempPurchase as (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (order by CustomerID) as rowNumber -- this is crucial part
    from purchase
)
select distinct(tp1.CustomerID) from tempPurchase as tp1 
join tempPurchase as tp2 on tp1.CustomerID = tp2.CustomerID 
    and tp1.DateOfPurchase >= tp2.DateOfPurchase
    and tp1.DateOfPurchase <= DATEADD(month, 6, tp2.DateOfPurchase)
    and tp1.rowNumber != tp2.rowNumber; -- this is crucial part
```

- Refer [db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d914138d06ae77bd8f4d85c53ef525d8) for complete working solution.

Comment: Note: This approach should _not_ at all be used in production.  Instead, just _fix_ the table design and add a primary key column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen any idea what should be done if this is a real life scenario and the PK or uniqueness doesn't exist naturally ?

Comment: Then maybe your approach is one such way +1.  But only if the original schema cannot be changed (and even so, you should be pushing the table owner to fix the design).

Answer (score 1):

We can try using exists logic here to detect records for the same customer occurring within 6 months.  Then, find distinct customers, which implies that any such matching customer has at least two purchases.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID AND
                    t2.DateOfPurchase > t1.DateOfPurchase AND
                    t2.DateOfPurchase <= DATEADD(month, 6, t1.DateOfPurchase));
```

Note that this answer assumes that there would only be at most one distinct purchase per day by a given customer.  A better approach would be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID AND
                    t2.PK <> t1.PK AND
                    t2.DateOfPurchase >= t1.DateOfPurchase AND
                    t2.DateOfPurchase <= DATEADD(month, 6, t1.DateOfPurchase));
```

The above query reads as saying find, for each customer, any relationship between 2 records within 6 months of each other which are distinct purchases.  This assumes that the table has a `PK` primary key column.  Ideally, every table should have some kind of logical primary key.

Comment: Repost of previous comment. @TimBiegeleisen 1: Can you please explain the having part, i am skeptical regarding the situation where one of the record will fail in qualifying the where condition(the record from t2 whose date is < t1.date) causing count to remain 1 in case when the customer made exactly 2 purchases. 2: Probably this won't work for the cases when customer made exact 2 purchase in 6 month that too on same date.  would like to know if i am missing something here. Thank you

Comment: You're missing something.  The `WHERE` clause only matches pairs of dates which both are _not_ the same and are within 6 months of each other.  You should should setup a sample database and try the query.  This will also increase your chances of getting hired by Amazon (...maybe).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i setup the fiddle to get the idea but the query doesn't seem to be working for both the situations that i was skeptical about and please let me know if i made any mistake, please have a look -> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e36d9e4f2747d2841fd086601768e363

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen TBH this isn't a solution since now this is matching the SAME record wit itself(same not similar or duplicate) instead of 2 different record, please check the fiddle where the purchase window is more than 6 months and the record is still qualified due to matching with itself -> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce207c8228f820d22ac473a31ef0ef0e

Comment: Exactly, we need to have a third column that is not there in OP's situation, that's why it becomes very tricky to do it but can be done by assigning a manual unique identifier SOMETHING like https://stackoverflow.com/a/67758032/8057127.

Comment: @Tim - thanks for taking your time out man, but could you please try to be a bit polite :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct CustomerID
FROM purchase t1
WHERE 1 < (SELECT count(1) FROM purchase t2
              WHERE t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID AND
                    t2.DateOfPurchase >= t1.DateOfPurchase AND
                    t2.DateOfPurchase <= DATEADD(month, 6, t1.DateOfPurchase))
```

Idea is to pick one record from outer table t1 and check in inner table t2 if there are any purchases made within 6 months including the one which you picked from outer table. If count from subquery is greater than 1 then we have the eligible customer.